# How to safe-cast a null into a generic type <T>?

Tags: kotlin, generics, casting, null

I want to know if there's a way to make a safe cast from null, the next example throws an UNCHECKED CAST warning:

```
fun <T> notInitialized(): T = null as T
```

So, If anyone has an idea of how to make a safe cast from this function please let me know!

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? It always returns _null_, never an instance of _T_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the generic answer (which is the usual way to approach these things),  you could do this:

```
fun notInitialised(): Nothing? = null
```

[`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) is the ‘bottom’ type, which has no values and is the subset of all other types. So `Nothing?` is a type with just one value (null), and is a subtype of all nullable types. This means you can assign it to any nullable type without needing any type inference, e.g.:

```
val a: Int? = notInitialised()
```

But I still don't understand the purpose of this — it doesn't seem to have any benefit over just using `null` directly. If you're using `null` to represent an uninitialised value (as opposed to an unknown value, a missing value, an inapplicable value, an unavailable value, an undefined value, an unchanged value, a secret value, or any of the other subtly-different things that people use null to mean), then that should be spelled out in the property/method/variable's doc comment — in which case there's no point spelling it out *again* in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `fun <T> notInitialized(): T? = null` - you need to return a nullable type (otherwise your cast is explicitly unsafe), and since you're already specifying the return type you don't need to cast `null as T?`. Or you could do that and skip the return type, `fun <T> notInitialized() = null as T?`

Either way you're just returning *null*, which isn't any specific type - you're just telling the caller to treat it as one. And that type needs to be nullable